# Only Some Filename Extension Needed When Compiling -- Why?

Tags: compiling

Consider the following file named `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

If I want to compile using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`, I can use

```
latex test
dvips test
```

for the first two steps.

Now to my question: why I have to use

```
ps2pdf test.ps
```

instead of just

```
ps2pdf test
```

to get the last step in the compiling process?

Comment: Because that's how `ps2pdf` work. Ask the maintainers of Ghostscript. Really, there's nothing more than this.

Comment: This is similar to `\input{test.tex}` *vs* `\input{test}`. It's by-design to add/assume `.tex` if you don't supply it. `ps2pdf` does the same but will either use `.ps` or `.eps`, in some order of preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The support for a default extension is a feature. Some programs support this, some not. `ps2pdf` of ghostscript is quite old and comes in different flavors, a shell script for Unix, batch for DOS/Windows, ...; my guess is, that the intention was to keep is short and simple.

There is also a downside to default extensions. It raises the ambiguity issue. Which file is loaded, if there is a file with the default extension and the file without extension? Should the specified file tried first, because it is the specified file after all, or should the file with the default extension be used, which is more appropriate for the application? Thus, not using a default extension provides a more robust and clear interface.